# JQuery .addclass() after page load

Tags: php, load, addclass, removeclass

I asign class to element but after loading page the class is removed.

I use this function in my script.js

```
$('#main-nav li ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#main-nav li ul li').children().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

and this in my PHP view:

```
 <ul id="main-nav">  <!-- Accordion Menu -->
    <li>
       <a href="#" class="nav-top-item no-submenu"> <!-- Add the class "no-submenu" to menu items with no sub menu -->
    On site
       </a>       
    </li>

    <li> 
       <a href="#" class="nav-top-item current"> <!-- Add the class "current" to current menu item -->
    Programs
       </a>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/country_management')?>">Manage country</a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/channel_management')?>">Manage channel</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Manage Comments</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Manage Categories</a></li>
    </ul>
       </li>

</ul> <!-- End #main-nav -->
```

If I use this `<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('...')?>">Manage</a></li>` the class current is added but after load is removed.

How can I add class if I use php code after load page or have you any solution ?

Comment: if u want to execute the code after page load then use $(document).ready(function(){ //code //});  If u want the execute the after the image load then use window.onload function

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is  scripting language ... When loading the page it will definitely remove your previous functionality as click event doesn't fired so it won't work....

After loading the page just put some logic through PHP ....

Answer (score 0):

with JQuery you can execute code when page is loaded :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Hi. My code is executing but after that class is removed. I need to asign class after page load or add class 1 more time to the element ul li a.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-nav li > a').click(function(e){
        $('#main-nav a').removeClass('current');
        $(e.target).addClass('current');
    });

});
```

if it doesn't work, try this block of script before `</body>` at the end of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#main-nav li > a').click(function(e){
        $('#main-nav a').removeClass('current');
        $(e.target).addClass('current');
    });
});
</script>
```

this will force the execution after all the html is rendered by the php

Answer (score 0):

First of all wrap your function in a `$(document). ready(function () {})` and use the `$('#main-nav'). on('click', 'li > a', function () {} )` approach inside of it. `. on()` is better to attach event listener to an dynamically loaded elements.